# How to get the values in a session to dataset using a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I have a session which includes a data table in it. Now i want to get **each number and store it in the database** using a `foreach` loop. I have tried a code. But it shows this error message. "

> Cannot convert type 'char' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'"

How can i do it?
Here is my code

```
protected void policyDetails()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string cellVal = "";

    foreach (ListItem item in Session["PolicyTable"].ToString())
    {
        cellVal = item.ToString();
        ds = db.insertPolicyDetails(cellVal);
    }
}
```

This is how create the session

```
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Policy_No"] = txtPolicy.Text.Trim();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
grdPolicyDetails.DataSource = dt;
grdPolicyDetails.DataBind();
Session["PolicyTable"] = dt;
```

Comment: Can you show how are you inserting the datatable in session?

Comment: @Richa, I will edit the question and add the code you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is coming because you are iterating over the `Session["PolicyTable"]` as ListItem. Change this to `DataRow`. Also if the session variable contains the datatable, you will be iterating over rows which cant be a string. Even if it contains a single column, you should retreive its value as:

```
DataTable dtSessionTable = (DataTable)Session["PolicyTable"];

foreach (DataRow item in dtSessionTable.Rows)
{
    cellVal = item["Policy_No"].ToString();
    ds = db.insertPolicyDetails(cellVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is in this line

```
cellVal = item.ToString();
```

This should be either :

```
cellVal = item.Text;
```

or

```
cellVal = item.Value;
```